# Background clickable and not the text

Tags: html, css

I have a field and when you click on `Google` the website opens. But my problem is that I want to click on the whole field and not only on the text!

```css
.section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.alignment {
    width: 500px;
}
#back-style {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    line-height: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="alignment">
        <div id="back-style">
            <a href=https://www.google.com">Google</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider making `#back-style` the link element. You'd need to apply `display: block` and remove `color: white` to have it look the same as your original code.

```css
.section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.alignment {
    width: 500px;
}
#back-style {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    line-height: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="alignment">
        <a id="back-style" href="https://www.google.com">
            Google
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<a>` tag is what makes something clickable. It should extend across the whole section that you want to be clickable, so I pulled it out of the div:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="alignment">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <div id="back-style">Google</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```